# File operation in Java

Tags: java

I have file reader object in Java.

When we load the file in, is entire file loaded or only file pointer will be loaded like in C. Because I have application (producer) wherein it keeps on writing to the file  and other application (consumer) will start to read the file after few minutes, I want to read all file data which will be written by the application producer.

I tried to search but could not get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `FileReader` works a lot like a `FileInputStream`, which in turn works a lot like its C analogue -- when you first open a file, very little data will actually be loaded immediately.  The file's contents generally aren't read in til you first `read` some of it, at which point the runtime reads enough to fill the request, or the buffer if you're using a BufferedReader (possibly plus enough to fill up a block, depending on the OS and JVM).

When i say it "works like its C analogue", though, i mean it.  A `FileReader` is opened for reading, and a `FileWriter` is opened for writing.  There could be issues with having a file open for reading and writing at the same time.  Windows, in particular, isn't too fond of it.  If you care about portability, you may want to find another way -- [alphazero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396116/319403) sounds promising, but i've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Best and canonical approach would be to use [Java NIO memory mapped files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).  Use [MappedByteBuffer.force()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#force%28%29) on each write to insure the consumer process flushes the dirty page files. Consumers (in other process if necessary) can map the same file in read mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean when you wrote, "when we load the file in".  Sample code would be helpful here.  Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

If you've called anything that sounds like "read" on your `Reader` then you've got data in memory.  If this is text data (assuming you're using `FileReader`) then you're better off using a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). Not only is it buffered, it's more convenient for text files.

If I have the answer all wrong then please post some code so I know what you're talking about.  And welcome!